# Почему не получается прервать корутину?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет. Есть такой код -

```
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Reload") && !InRealod && Ammo < MaxAmmo)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ReloadCountdown());
    }
    if (InRealod && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire") && Ammo != 0)
    {
        StopCoroutine(ReloadCountdown());
    }
    IEnumerator ReloadCountdown()
    {
        while (Ammo < MaxAmmo)
        {
            InRealod = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(ReloadTime);
            Ammo++;
            InRealod = false;
        }
    }
```

Но корутина не прерывается. Все условия соблюдаются. Но она сама прерывается когда Ammo == MaxAmmo. Даже если сделать так -

```
IEnumerator ReloadCountdown()
{
    while (Ammo < MaxAmmo && !Input.GetButtonDown("Fire"))
    {
        InRealod = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(ReloadTime);
        Ammo++;
        InRealod = false;
    }
}
```

ничего не получается. Идея такая - зарядка патронов в оружие должна идти пока игрок не нажмёт на кнопку огня(если Ammo != 0). Почему не получается прервать корутину?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строчке StopCoroutine(ReloadCountdown()) - вы по факту сначала запускаете новую корутину перезарядки, а затем её же и останавливаете. Вам нужно кешировать корутину, которую возвращает StartCoroutine(), а в метод StopCoroutine передавать ссылку на неё. К тому же проверку ссылки на корутину перезарядки можно использовать вместо флага InRealod. Внизу код реализации.

А во втором случае ваша проблема связана с тем, что проверка на ввод осуществляется не каждый кадр. Когда вы вызываете yield return new WaitForSeconds(ReloadTime) - корутина приостанавливается на длительность этого таймера и только потом продолжает выполнение. Т.е. она не будет знать нажали вы кнопку или нет, пока она ждала.

```
    Coroutine _reloadRoutine;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Reload") && _reloadRoutine == null && Ammo < MaxAmmo)
        {
            _reloadRoutine = StartCoroutine(ReloadCountdown());
        }
        if (_reloadRoutine != null && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire") && Ammo != 0)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_reloadRoutine);
            _reloadRoutine = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ReloadCountdown()
    {
        while (Ammo < MaxAmmo)
        {
            InRealod = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(ReloadTime);
            Ammo++;
            InRealod = false;
        }
        _reloadRoutine = null;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Еще вопрос: как сделать, чтобы зарядка не прерывалась пока патрон не зашел в патронник? То-есть, идёт процесс зарядки одной пули -> нажимается Fire и как только пуля зайдет в патронник корутина остановиться? А то если добавить анимацию перезарядки, могут начаться проблемы. Например, идет анимация перезарядки, игрок нажимает Fire, пуля(в коде) уже в патроннике, а в анимации он только достаёт её.

Comment: @xomem, ну, я вижу решение именно через добавление анимации зарядки пули. У Unity есть класс StateMachineBehaviour - его, как и его наследников можно вешать внутрь аниматора и подписываться на его события. В том числе он сообщает, когда аниматор выходит из определённого стейта получая в метод хеш имени этого стейта. Как вариант - пулю в патронник засчитывать именно, когда произойдёт выход из состояния "заряжаю". А при нажатии выстрела не останавливать корутину, а ставить флаг прерывания. И если при выходе из стейта "перезарядка" флаг стоит - прерывать корутину.

Comment: спасибо ещя раз