# Таймер выполнения метода, с возможностью его прервать

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть кнопка и метод, который выполняется 3сек.
Нужно запустить метод и проверить, если кнопка нажата, то выполнить действие №1, не ожидая 3сек и заново запустить метод; если не нажата за 3сек, то выполнить действие №2 и снова запустить метод.

Пробовал это сделать с помощью корутины, но я не могу понять как прервать ожидание в 3сек после нажатия на кнопку и из-за этого выполняется действие №2.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Interval());
}

IEnumerator Interval()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    print("Действие №2"); // Действие которое должно выполняться если кнопка не нажата и прошло 3сек
    StartCoroutine(Interval());
}

public void BtnPressed()
{
    // После нажатия не ждем 3сек, а выполняем Действие №1
    StopCoroutine(Interval());
    StartCoroutine(Interval());
    print("Действие №1");
}
```

Можно ли это как-то провернуть? Или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Думаю нужно сделать как в инструкции https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html       То есть coroutine = Interval();    StartCoroutine(coroutine );   StopCoroutine(coroutine )

Comment: Действие 1 перед стартом поставь. Где логика?

Comment: @Methorn Тут Действие №1 даже не важно, разве я спрашиваю как выполнить его? Мне нужно после нажатия прервать выполнение `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f)` и запустить корутину еще раз.

Comment: @D1000 1 минуту загуглил. Если вкратце "Когда вы вызываете yield return new WaitForSeconds(time) - корутина приостанавливается на длительность этого таймера и только потом продолжает выполнение. Т.е. она не будет знать нажали вы кнопку или нет, пока она ждала." 
[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778317/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: @Methorn Именно в этом и проблема, т.к. после нажатия на кнопку корутина не останавливается и параллельно у меня начинается другая корутина, которая тоже ждет 3сек. Похоже с помощью корутины не получится это сделать.